# DataBind on the DataContext of the UserControl instead of the ListBox in WPF/MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I need to bind my ComboBox to the 'Rayons' property of the DataContext from the UserControl (instead of the ItemSources of the ListView which contains my ComboBox).

I tried to use RelativeSource but it doesn't work and I've no error message in the debug window.

A simplified code :

```
<UserControl xmlns:my="clr-UI.View"
             x:Class="UI.View.MontureView"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="673" d:DesignWidth="980">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Monture, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,39,0,95" Height="600" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="125"
                                          Name="comboBoxRay" Margin="0,2,0,3"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rayons,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=IDRayon, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="SRAY_LIBELLE"
                                          SelectedValuePath="SRAY_ID"  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

How can I handle that case ?

I found that [documentation](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf) but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several way how to handle this. but first if you dont see a binding error try using Snoop to see if there Binding errors.

nevertheless if you use RelativeSource binding your Path should alomost be something like: Path=**DataContext**.Rayons. in your case the binding need a Rayons property on your usercontrol, but there is of course no Rayons property.

the relativesource binding like you did works most time, but when you have a usercontrol in a usercontrol in a usercontrol it becomes difficult ;) is such cases i use **DataContextMarkerInterface**(empty interfaces).

```
public interface IDataContextMarkerRayonsSource {}
```

then add this interface to your specific usercontrol and change the relativesource binding to AncestorType

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Rayons, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:IDataContextMarkerRayonsSource }}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You say it: property from the `DataContext` of `UserControl`. Try

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Rayons,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```